# How to include a framework?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm trying to use VideoJS but I don't understand the files I have to include. This is not proper to VideoJS because I've had this problem with other frameworks : Inside the zip, there are different folders like "dist", "lib", etc.

Since there is videojs-background.js (seems to be the only JavaScript file ton include), in both folders, which one do I have to include ? 
Do I need something else ?

Thank you

@edit : Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain what these folders are ?

Comment: if there is a `dist` use what's in there. Or use a cdn source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on which library you are trying to include and whether you use any module bundler in your app. Therefore, you should consult the README / documentation of the library. In your example of video.js, there is a [Getting Started](http://videojs.com/getting-started/) guide on their homepage that explains various ways to include the code.

Regarding your question about different folders: most of the time, the downloads include both the source code of the library (often in directories like `src`, `lib`), as well as some bundled-minified code (often in directories like `dist`, `bundle` and with file ending `.min.js`)

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html

> If you simply copy the dist folder or zip file contents into your project everything should Just Work™

Comment: Well doesn't reading the documentation thoroughly just make it too simple to figure out

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is just use [a CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), although this can have it's [advantages and disadvantages](http://www.alphansotech.com/blogs/should-you-use-cdn/). Since I am not super experienced in this area, I would recommend taking a look at the linked artcicle or searching yourself for the pros and cons, but I have never had any issues.

For example, for Video.js, you can add the following in the `<head>` of the document that is using this library for the css:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And for the JavaScript, add the following in the `<body>` of the document:

```
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video.js"></script>
```

Here is a full example from [the docs](http://videojs.com/getting-started/#download-cdn):

```
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video.js"></script>
</body>
```